# Push after commit with WebStorm

Tags: git, version-control, webstorm

Is there a way to add a git push menu item or icon to the Version Control -> Log -> individual commit?
The way to git push an item there I found was to add the git push icon to the main toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to add a menu in Log window, but you can achieve it with any of below options:

#### Option 1: Select Commit and Push instead of Commit when committing changes

When you committing the local changes, you can select **Commit and Push** so thee local changes will be pushed immediately after committing changes.

[image]

#### Option 2: use the keyboard shortcut for push operation when needed

Use you use the predefined keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+K** to open the push window when you are ready.